# Homomorphisms, kernel, basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with the following problem. Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $3$ and $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ its basis. Let $W$ be a vector space of dimension $2$ and $\{w_1, w_2\}$ as its basis.

$f$ is defined as a transformation from $V$ to $W$ so that

$f(\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3v_3)=
(\lambda_1+\mu)w_1+(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)w_2$

a) find the values of $\mu$ so that $f$ is linear

b) for the values in a), determine a basis of $\ker(f)$

We know a transformation is linear if and only if a) $f(u+w) = f(u) + f(w)$ and $f(ku) = kf(u)$. However, after developing both cases I have reached no particular conclusion. What now?

Comment: It should be $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You mean the third rule, the image of the 0 vector must be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It should be $f(0)=0$.

Alternative hint: it is not restrictive to assume that $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^2$, the bases being the canonical ones. In case the map is linear, its associated matrix  would be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\mu & \mu & \mu \\
0     & 1   & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But then
$$
f(\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3v_3)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\mu & \mu & \mu \\
0     & 1   & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(1+\mu)\lambda_1+\mu\lambda_2+\mu\lambda_3\\
\lambda_2+\lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which should be equal to $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1+\mu\\\lambda_2+\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$ (what results from the actual definition of $f$) *for all* choices of $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$.

Now, what values of $\mu$ make
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(1+\mu)\lambda_1+\mu\lambda_2+\mu\lambda_3\\
\lambda_2+\lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1+\mu\\
\lambda_2+\lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for all $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$? If you find such values, you'll also have that the function $f$ is linear (because it coincides with the action of the associated matrix).

Comment: I'll give this a look as soon as possible! Thanks.

Comment: I can't figure out how the associated matrix turns out to be (1 + µ, µ, µ) and (0 1 1). The following one, however, seems pretty logical!

Comment: @Alexandre If $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ you get $f(v_1)=(1+\mu)w_1=\begin{bmatrix}1+\mu\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Just do the same for the other two cases.

Comment: oh, now it makes sense. Thank you for the clarification. I'll see if I can figure out the rest!

Comment: Sorry for being such a bother - I'm frustrated for not understanding the whole deal, let alone you for explaining it over and over. In the second matrix, how does the multiplication return the third matrix? Shouldn't it yield ((1 + µ)λ1 + µλ2 + µλ3),(0 + λ2 + λ3)?

Comment: @Alexandre The multiplication indeed gives $\begin{bmatrix}(1+\mu)\lambda_1+\mu\lambda_2+\mu\lambda_3\\ \lambda_2+\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$. But your definition of $f$ is not this; if $f$ is linear the two expressions should agree.

Comment: @ egreg I'm sorry, but I need a bit more insight into it if possible. I have no idea what has been done until now...EDIT: I mean, I suppose we could get the third matrix from the definition. But your last comment broke me! How are we relating linearity to the two matrices?